# How to avoid indicator deforming in expandable list view with custom images?

Tags: android

When I don't set group indicator in expandable list it works fine and default indicator is shown left side. I want to put custom indicators with custom images (arrow_down.png and arrow_right.png).

[image] **and** [image]

which have dimensions `100 x 100` and I put in xml in ExpanadableListView

```
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/indicator"
```

where indicator is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right"></item>
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right"></item>
</selector>
```

but it totally deform images, especially when I expand row.
How to solve this and avoid indicator deforming ?

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: see the following link for seeing how it is done http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html